# Маппинг по нерегулярной трехмерной LUT-таблице

Tags: алгоритм

Где найти реализацию отображения (маппинга) с помощью нерегулярной (неравномерной) 3D LUT-таблицы. Нужно для цветового маппинга.

Очень не хочется самому писать, многовато работы, это, насколько я понимаю, надо делать тетраэдризацию Делоне набора точек LUT, потом высчитывать, чему принадлежит входная точка (тетраэдру, грани между тетраэдрами, внешней грани, внешнему пространству за всеми тетраэдрами), потом взвешивать соответствующие найденные точки, ещё и вырожденные случаи рассматривать....

Может, кто встречал готовые исходники в какой нибудь библиотеке. Желательно на C/C++, но пойдёт любой язык.

Во избежание возможных разночтений: речь не идет об обычном non-uniform lattice, маппинг по которому делается комбинацией двух маппингов  3*1D LUT + 3D LUT, а речь идет о нерегулярном (например, стохастическом) распределении вокселов/опорных точек 3D LUT. Я проиллюстрировал на вложенной картинке.
[image: нерегулярное распределение вокселов]